# Error: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Tags: python-3.x, math

It says the error is when h (altitude) is between 11000 and 25000, so I only posted the initial stuff outside all my if loops and the specific loop where the problem is happening. Here is my code:

```
import math;
T = 0.0;
P = 0.0;
hString = ("What is the altitude in meters?");
h = int(hString);
e = math.exp(0.000157*h);

elif 11000 < h < 25000:
   T = -56.46;
   P = (22.65)*[(1.73)-e];
```

Comment: Your code gives me `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'What is the altitude in meters?'`. Can you correct your code example so it runs when copy-pasted into a Python console?

Comment: Please post code that actually produces the error that you're reporting. This page on writing an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help.

Answer (score 3):

When you use mathematical operations you need to be careful with brackets.

```
    P = (22.65)*((1.73)-e); #will be right way of using
```

> [ ] using will create a list which you, do not need in this program.

Here is a [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/numbers) which will help you learn much more about type conversions and proper use of brackets while doing mathematics on it.

**Also in your code you have not used**

```
      hString =input ("What is the altitude in meters?");
      h = int(hString);
```

input will allow you to take value from user and then `int(your_input)` will help you convert to integer

Comment: `P = (22.65)*)(1.73)-e)` does not look right to me. Did you mean: `P = (22.65)*((1.73)-e)`?

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets in the last line (`[(1.73)-e]`) create a list. In this case, it's a list with one element, namely `(1.73)-e`. I imagine you intended those to be parens. Make that change and it will work.

The final line becomes:

```
P = (22.65)*((1.73)-e);
```